# Checking authentication with play2-auth

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In the code below, there's  a play2-auth authorization check. In the first method it checks that the authority required is `NormalUser` and in the second method `Administrator`.

In my case, there may be even more roles (such as `Security Officer`) that are created by the user. Is it possible to have StackAction check against a user role that is dynamically created in the system?

```
  def detail(id: Int) = StackAction(AuthorityKey -> NormalUser) { implicit request =>
    val title = "messages detail "
    Ok(html.message.detail(title + id))
  }

  def write = StackAction(AuthorityKey -> Administrator) { implicit request =>
    val title = "write message"
    Ok(html.message.write(title))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that **by extending Role** as per your requirement.

In your case, you can do something like:

```
case object Security Officer extends Role
```

You can see that in the **Usage** section in the readme here:

https://github.com/t2v/play2-auth

For better **dynamic role based authorization**, you might wanna have a look at deadbolt:

https://deadbolt-scala.readme.io/docs

You should also look at how **activity based checks** can be implemented instead of role based authorizations :

https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/

Hope this helps :)